# Location of berryboot's config.txt

Tags: boot, raspbian-wheezy, u-boot

Related to another question I've asked earlier:

Where is the berryboot's 'config.txt' physically located on the raspberry pi? And how would I access it via command line or similar?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, please mark the answer that helped you, or if you solved it on your own, create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and marking answers is what does that. If you resolved it and mark then people in the future will be able to profit from what you did *and* it helps move the site closer to graduation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First of all 'Raspberry Pi' is not an operating system so you have to tell the name which linux distribution you're using.

I'm using BerryBoot to boot my 4 linux distribution which are installed on my USB disk.

To find out where the config.txt and to modifying it, you have to mount BerryBoot installed device. It's formatted as FAT32.

```
Find the device name;  
root@pi:~# fdisk -l |grep dev
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3904 MB, 3904897024 bytes
/dev/mmcblk0p1               2     7626751     3813375    b  W95 FAT32
Disk /dev/sda: 16.4 GB, 16441671680 bytes
/dev/sda1          131072    32112639    15990784   83  Linux
Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
/dev/sdb1              63  2930272064  1465136001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Then mount the device somewhere and look for config.txt

```
root@pi:~# mkdir /berry
root@pi:~# mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /berry
root@pi:~# ls -l /berry
total 45092
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    30776 Feb 12 08:48 LICENSE.berryboot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8170528 Mar 11 04:29 berryboot.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    17816 Jul 19 17:10 bootcode.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      134 Jul 19 16:25 cmdline.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      133 Apr  9 21:53 cmdline.txt~
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      173 Jul 19 17:25 config.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     5886 Jul 19 17:10 fixup.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     2032 Jul 19 17:10 fixup_cd.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     8842 Jul 19 17:10 fixup_x.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2805264 Jul 19 17:10 kernel.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3609232 Mar 11 03:50 kernel_a10_aufs.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9616160 Jul 19 17:10 kernel_emergency.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2753200 Mar 11 04:29 kernel_rpi_aufs.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12294570 Mar 11 04:29 shared.tgz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2690164 Jul 19 17:10 start.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   469208 Jul 19 17:10 start_cd.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3657572 Jul 19 17:10 start_x.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      413 Feb 25 00:24 uEnv.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You had to create a partition and put berryboot's files there on install; these also contained a `config.txt`. I suspect your question asks how to access this from within one of the distributions you installed. 
Under `openelec` it's in `/var/media/<some id>`, `raspbian` and `archlinux on arm` install it under `/boot/`. A semi user friendly console editor is `nano` which you would start with `nano <file>`.